# Using Kohana's Auth module

Tags: php, kohana

Well, its has been almost two hours but I can't get Kohana 3.1 Auth module working.

I followed this blog: http://jdstraughan.com/post/auth-module-for-kohana-31-using-orm-driver and i am able to figure out how to implement the login but i am completely clueless about the registration part: How to insert in the tables of Auth_schema?

I thought I might just have to extend some other model but I don't know which. Another option for me is to do it manually using `Auth::instance()->hash()` for password but I am not sure if this is the only way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, what kind of errors do you get? I uses something like this and everything fine:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user');
$user->values($_POST);
$user->save();
```

Authe_schema the same, Kohana 3.1

Comment: For extanding ORM use Model_Auth_User class

Comment: so we have to build a class in models folder which extents Model_Auth_user?

Comment: If you want to **extend** default user ORM, yes, you have to.